# Redux, Redux-persist, cannot read property "age" of undefined

Tags: react-native, redux, undefined, redux-form, redux-persist

I am using *Redux* with a *React Native* app, and am getting a red box error when trying to integrate *Redux-Persist*. As soon as I navigate to the initial screen which has a *ProfileForm* and has the `this.props.age` piece of state, I see this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "age" of undefined
```

I am not quite sure where I am going wrong. I have set initial value of `age = 0` in the reducer. So how is it `undefined`? Here is code that would be relevant:

**reducers/UserReducer.js**

```
import { CALCULATE_BMI, CALCULATE_AGE } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { bmi: 0, age: 0 };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CALCULATE_BMI:
      return { ...state, bmi: action.bmi };
    case CALCULATE_AGE:
      return { ...state, age: action.age };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import userReducer from './UserReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  form: formReducer,
});
```

**store/index.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage'; // default: localStorage if web, AsyncStorage if react-native
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import reducers from '../reducers';

const config = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const reducer = persistCombineReducers(config, { reducers });

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(reducer, {}, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)));
  const persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { persistor, store };
};
```

**ProfileForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-
native';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import DatePickerModal from '../components/DatePickerModal';

class ProfileForm extends Component {
  // other code here
  <Field name="birthdate" component={DatePickerModal} />
    {this.props.age === 0 ? null : (
      <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>{`Age: ${this.props.age}`}</Text>
    )} 
  //other code here
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  age: state.user.age,
});

export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, actions), reduxForm({ form: 'Profile', validate }))(
  ProfileForm,
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react';
import MainNavigator from './routes';
import configureStore from './store';

const { persistor, store } = configureStore();

export default class App extends Component {
  // other code here
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          <MainNavigator />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried removing the empty object {} passed to *createStore*, setting it as undefined, and setting the initial values here instead, but nothing seems to work. Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: I think your problem is inside `ProfileForm.js` and inside `mapStateToProps`. It's specifically this line `age: state.user.age,`. You have no `user` property on your state object and thus `state.user` is undefined. Look at your `reducers/UserReducer.js` file, you're setting an `age` property on the `state`. Change the line inside the mapStateToProps to `age: state.age,`

Comment: Isn't the user piece of state defined in combineReducers? I have tried making those changes, but the form submission returns undefined values.

Comment: So i changed `age: state.user.age` to `age: state.age` and also to `age: state.reducers.user.age`, the 2nd part makes more sense to me, but still having same problems. In redux-logger I can see the state being updated with redux-form's `@@redux-form-CHANGE` action type. However, the values received by redux-form's handlesubmit function are undefined. As a result my custom components are not updating. I hope that makes some sense...

Comment: for ```reducers/index.js``` instead of ```export default``` I would turn that into ```const rootReducer = combineReducers({``` and then ```export default rootReducer```.

Comment: @Daniel, any reason why? Have changed it but still same issues...

Comment: @Praveen, was just suggesting you apply ES6 object literal shorthand in the ```rootReducer``` since that is what I understand ```reducers/index.js``` to be.

Comment: @Praveen, Also, I don't understand this code ```export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, actions), reduxForm({ form: 'Profile', validate }))(
  ProfileForm,
);```. My understanding is that reduxForm is similar to the connect helper from react-redux, why use both? Why not just ```export default reduxForm({ form: 'ProfileForm'})(ProfileForm);```. Also, do you mind explaining a bit more about your app? Is it storing a users health data?

Comment: @Praveen, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Nope! I decided to skip redux-persist and store all data onto a backend server. Yes it is a health app storing some user data.